# Whenever I try to import material ui icons and core an error appears saying module not found? How to solve it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui

[This is the error shown whenever I try to use @material-ui/core and icons

```js
`import React from "react";
import "./Sidebar.CSS";
import SearchIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Search";

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="sidebar">
        <div className="sidebar__header">
          <SearchIcon />
        </div>
        <div className="sidebar__search"></div>
        <div className="sidebar__chats"></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

`][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1ZnN.jpg)

Comment: Hi Safal, in addition to your code please could you provide the error stack to read more about the error. That would help us help you

Comment: When you say "this is the error shown...", do you mean "this is the code that produces the error"? If so please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you have run

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/icons

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

Because if you haven't then react won't know where to look for the icons

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because of the following reasons.

1. Material UI is not installed properly.
   Delete the material UI package from node modules folder.Add material UI package under dependencies (not under devDependencies) and delete package-lock.json and try non install again
2. SearchIcon will be a named export
   Use  `import { SearchIcon  } from "@material-ui/icons/Search";`

Answer (score 0):

Have you maybe not done the following?

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

And then also:

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/icons

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/icons
```

If you are taking it from this website (https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/) then you need to install the `core` as well. As explained here (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/)